# How do I change the terminal font?

Tags: ssh, terminal, fonts

I notice a difference in the terminal font between two of my Android devices, specifically in terms of character coverage (in both cases it's the terminal shell of JuiceSSH).  How do I set the font that the terminal uses in Android?

Comment: Increase/decrease general system wide font size by going to `Settings` > `Display` > `Change Font Size` or similar. Or if that specific application offers font size preference, then use it. Different android devices' font don't look the same because of screen sizes and resolutions / dpi.

Answer (score 2):

I found two ways for changing font size in [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh).

### Use Volume keys

The very first time you would've used JuiceSSH, you might have come across this brief tutorial:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG:]

Use the Volume Up/Down keys to adjust the size of the font.

### Traditional way (Settings)

On the default page of JuiceSSH, go to Settings → Font size → adjust it.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score -2):

Use the Volume keys of your phone to adjust the font.